# On the usage: Yes, please

Tags: word-usage

I was watching a movie. A girl asked a boy:

```
Hey, Rex, can you help me?
```

The boy answered:

```
Yes, please.
```

Then they went out to a date (kind of).

I am not exactly sure about the `please` part. I haven't seen it used like this before. It's usually in the question. Not the answer.

I was wondering if there are other examples of such usage, to illustrate?

Thanks.

-- EDIT --

This was from a Science Fiction movie. Both the actor and the actress seem to be native English speakers. This is not like a western movie where the cowboys say things that are plainly wrong in grammar. The language there was actually slightly poetic, although they were still kids.

Comment: Might be a good idea if you could tell us the title of the film, it may or may not be relevant to your question, but it would provide further context.

Comment: It's a science fiction (kind of) movie called: "Battle for Skyark".

Comment: And the person who replied "Yes, please?" was he an alien? (just looked through the plot very quickly). *In the near future the earth has become desolate and dangerous. Now inhabited by by a mysterious race of creatures, humanity has been forced to find refuge in the SkyArk, a man-made city in the sky. As the population grows, space becomes scarce and only the rich and powerful can stay*

Comment: No, no. The boy looks English-speaking and from-earth. There is no accent or awkward language usage that I can spot.

Comment: But he's an orphan, right? Without any parents and presumably without any formal education. Can he read and write? How old is he?

Comment: ADD THAT INFO in your post! :) Someone will have seen this movie. Safe to say that this reply is not typical, and without seeing the movie, I can only guess that perhaps the boy is terribly embarrassed facing the girl, maybe she's real pretty, and he gets tongue-tied.

Comment: it is simply impossible to answer this question, unless you supply (for example) a video extract of the section, or more dialogue.   it **could be** a jokey romantic thing (like this: **"Hey! I should slap you for that!" "Yes please!"**) or it could be a idiosyncracy of the character..  Or just a plain "typo" in the movie (which is utterly commonplace). As it stands, all comments and answers are, really, not helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '**please**' is odd, as you say.  It is put in to change the context, recontextualise, the conversation. Rex is saying that he will respond, and he is glad to take on the task.
Here is the subtext as I read it,

> **Hey Rex, can you help me?**
>
> **Yes**, of course.  She's asking me! I didn't think she'd ever ask me.
>   Yes **please**, I'd like to help.

But in a cool, laid back, way. I ought not to be telling you the subtext without seeing the whole episode but I hope this suggests an answer.

Comment: That's what I thought. Just haven't seen the word used this way before.

Answer (score 2):

Uhm...I've noticed the usage of 'Yes, please' in this song called 'Sugar' by Maroon 5. It goes something like this: 'Sugar? Yes, please'
I think the *please* in the phrase suggests 'Please go ahead and do so'.

For ex: Sugar?(Do you need some sugar?)
        Yes, please(a polite way of accepting the offer)

In the example that you provided, *please* suggests that the boy is happy to accept the girl's request for help.

Comment: but that's the completely normal way to use please.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to know without the full context, but I can certainly imagine a movie scene where the girl is asking if the boy can help her with something, and that *something* is fun in nature (for example: sexual, taboo but desirable, illegal but desirable).

In this case the answer "Yes please" means that not only is the boy able to help about, but very much relishes the idea of helping out... A bit like "Hell yeah!"...

Answer (score 0):

I found on WordReference this comment:

[...] "Yes, please" is a single utterance (the comma doesn't represent a break or pause, it seems only to be grammatical) where "Yes" is the response and please makes it polite. It is more natural and common to say simply "Please" in response to an offer: "yes" is redundant.

Comment: You've only cursorily answered the question title, please read the actual question itself.

Comment: If someone asks me "Would you like a coffee?" I can reply "Yes, please" There's nothing wrong with that, it's grammatical, the "please" is not redundant because it makes  the reply sound more polite than simply saying "Yes." (NOT my upvote)